# (JSF) form-based authentication with my own user management

Tags: authentication, jsf

I would like to use form-based authentication as outlined in the book JavaServer Faces (O'REILLY). But instead of letting Tomcat manage the users, I would like to manage them myself: store them in a database etc. Can anyone give me a few pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple example

http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3335001/BASIC-and-FORM-based-Authorization-in-Your-Web-Application.htm

Apache Documentation

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Standard_Realm_Implementations

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. I suppose I have to implement my own realm. I am using Hibernate. Any pointers for that?